# Extra fields on many-to-many relationships: How to automatically create the "through" fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use a many to many field in order to add a set of facilities to a lead.
The trouble is that i need an extra field for the date and time of the tour scheduled for each of the facilities i add to the lead.
So when i create a lead and add facilities to the lead i have that extra field where i can enter date and time and access it afterwards as a list of facilities with their tour dates on the leads page.

I came across many to many fields using "through" but I'm not sure if that's even the right option to use in this case. [ManyToMany Fields with extra fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

How can i use a many to many field using "through" and have the through field automatically be generated for each facility i add to my lead with the many to many field? Or is using through not a good option?

I'm using Django Rest Framework with a React Frontend:

models.py

```
class Facility(models.Model):

    Name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)
    mainimage = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    TelephoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    FacilityDescription = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name


class Lead(models.Model):
    assigned_facilities = models.ManyToManyField(Facility,  related_name='assigned_facilities', null=True, blank=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

serializers.py

```
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "assigned_facilities",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id")

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
```

Leads.js

```
    const cpBoard = useSelector((state) => state.cpBoard);
    const facilityIds = (cpBoard.cpBoardItems?.map(cpBoardItem => (cpBoardItem.id)));

    function submitFacilities() {

        axios.patch(API.leads.update(id), { "assigned_facilities": facilityIds}, {

            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
        })
            .then(res => {
                fetchLeads()

            })
            .finally(() => {                
            })
    }
```

## UPDATE:

I'm currently trying to use the solution suggested below but i'm getting an error when i try to update a lead:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scheduled_datetime' File "/serializers.py", line 253, in to_representation ret["scheduled_datetime"] = str(instance.leadfacilityassociation.first().scheduled_datetime)
```

models.py

```
class Facility(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)
    main_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    facility_description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name


class Lead(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"


class LeadFacilityAssociation(models.Model):
    assigned_facilities = models.ForeignKey(Facility,  related_name='leadfacilityassociation')
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead,  related_name='leadfacilityassociation')
    scheduled_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    assigned_facilities = serializers.Integer(required=True)
    scheduled_datetime = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "assigned_facilities",
            "scheduled_datetime",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id")

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        assigned_facilities = validated_data.pop("assigned_facilities")
        scheduled_datetime = validated_data.pop("scheduled_datetime")
        instance = Lead.objects.create(**validated_data)
        instance.leadfacilityassociation.create(assigned_facilities=assigned_facilities,scheduled_datetime=scheduled_datetime)
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret["scheduled_datetime"] = str(instance.leadfacilityassociation.first().scheduled_datetime)
        ret["assigned_facilities"] = instance.leadfacilityassociation.first().assigned_facilities
        return ret
```

Answer (score 4):

`ManyToManyField` is basically create another association model on Database level to associate ModelA(id) with ModelB(id). We are unable to add additional fields in it.

Now in your case, let's restructure the schema.

```
class Facility(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)
    main_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    facility_description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name


class Lead(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"


class LeadFacilityAssociation(models.Model):
    assigned_facilities = models.ForeignKey(Facility,  related_name='leadfacilityassociation')
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead,  related_name='leadfacilityassociation')
    scheduled_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

`Class Facility`:  The fields remains same in this `Model`.

`Class Model`: Remove `assigned_facilities` field from  because we no longer need it.

`Class LeadFacilityAssociation`: Adding this `Model` to associate the `Lead` and `Facility` with additional `scheduled_datetime` field. Now you are able to mapped multiple `Leads` with multiple `Facility` with separate `scheduled_datetime`.

**Serializer**

```
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    assigned_facilities = serializers.Integer(required=True)
    scheduled_datetime = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "assigned_facilities",
            "scheduled_datetime",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id")

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        assigned_facilities = validated_data.pop("assigned_facilities")
        scheduled_datetime = validated_data.pop("scheduled_datetime")
        instance = Lead.objects.create(**validated_data)
        instance.leadfacilityassociation.create(assigned_facilities=assigned_facilities,scheduled_datetime=scheduled_datetime)
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret["scheduled_datetime"] = str(instance.leadfacilityassociation.first().scheduled_datetime)
        ret["assigned_facilities"] = instance.leadfacilityassociation.first().assigned_facilities
        return ret
```

**Note**
This serializer is designed to create only one `Lead` with one `Facility`. For creating multiple facilities you can change the overrided method `create`. Use `bulk_create` for creating multiple facilities against `Lead`. Also change the `to_representation` method body for returning multiple facilities against `Lead`.

Comment: When i try this i receive the following error when i try to update a lead: AttributeError
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scheduled_datetime'
File "/serializers.py", line 253, in to_representation
ret["scheduled_datetime"] = str(instance.leadfacilityassociation.first().scheduled_datetime)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 3):

Using through= seems the way to go in your case. To achieve it you need to create a Model for your M2M table

```
LeadFacility(models.Model):
    facility = models.ForeignKey(Facility, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

You can set the datetime value using the following syntax :

```
my_lead.assigned_facilities.add(my_facility, through_defautlts={"datetime": my_datetime})
```

Or simply creating the LeadFacilty explicitly :

```
LeadFacility.objects.create(lead=my_lead, facility=my_facility, datetime=my_datetime)
```

To access those fields, you'll to define related_names in the LeadFacility model